# Firing php Script from Windows Command Line CMD

Tags: php, windows, command-line, cmd

I feel like I'm missing something here. **php is set up in my system variable PATH.** I'm trying to execute a php script from the Window command line, here is my script:

```
<?php
$file = "test_log.txt";
$content = date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . " - Action logged. \n";
file_put_contents($file, $content, FILE_APPEND);

echo "That worked. I think.";
?>
```

When called from my browser it works perfectly. A log file is appended with the latest action. However when called from the command line I get the **echo**, but nothing else happens, no appendment of the log file. See below:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: `file_put_contents('C:\\wwwroot\\'.$file, $content, FILE_APPEND);` ?

Comment: Ah! I'm an idiot! Thank you. That did the trick. Add your comment as an answer, I've got some meaningless internet points for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
file_put_contents(__DIR__.'/'.$file, $content, FILE_APPEND);
```

Reason: Your webserver has a different $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] (and current work directory) than the Command Line Interpreter.

Comment: It was your: __DIR__. '/'. solution that did it for me. Could edit your answer?